# Can a type match contain more general types, later in the match statement?

Tags: scala, scala-3, match-types

I'm learning Scala 3, and I'm trying to better learn about match types and literal types.

## The short version

I'm encountering a compile-time typing error when I'm using a type match that contains a case type that is more general than an earlier case type. Basically, I've got a match type that looks like this:

```scala
type MyMatchType[Index, +T0, +T1] = Index match {
  case 0 => T0
  case 1 => T1
  case Int => T0 | T1
}
```

When matching on a type literal of `0`, the result correctly types as `T0`. When matching on a type literal of `1`, the result correctly types as `T1`. However, when matching on a type of `Int`, I would *like* the inferred type to be `(T0 | T1)`, but it is *actually* `MyMatchType[Index, T0, T1]`.

## The longer version

For an example, I'd like to create my own `Tuple2`. I'd like `MyTuple2` to behave as you'd expect:

```scala
val x = MyTuple2[Int, String](99, "Luftballoons")
x(0)  // 99: Int
x(1)  // "Luftballoons": String
```

I'd like to support some kind of dynamic access with `Int`s that are not known at compile-time:

```scala
val zero: Int = 0
val two: Int = 2
x(zero)  // 99
x(two)  // java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
```

I've gotten a lot of this working with a match type and a case class for the tuple:

```scala
type MyTuple2Apply[Index, +T0, +T1] = Index match {
  case 0 => T0
  case 1 => T1
  case Int => T0 | T1
}

case class MyTuple2[+T0, +T1](private val v0: T0, private val v1: T1):

  def apply[Index](i: Index): MyTuple2Apply[i.type, T0, T1] =
    i match
      case _: 0 => v0
      case _: 1 => v1
      case _: Int =>
        // This logic isn't 100% right but don't worry about it for this example.
        throw new IllegalArgumentException
```

Here, everything works correctly *except for the types*. In particular, I would like this to work:

```
// This should type as (Int | String), because all the compiler knew was that I
// passed an Int to apply. MyTuple2Apply here should map Int => (Int | String).
x(zero): (Int | String)
```

However, I get this error message:

```
1 |x(zero): (Int | String)
  |^^^^^^^
  |Found:    MyTuple2Apply[(zero : Int), Int, String]
  |Required: Int | String
  |
  |Note: a match type could not be fully reduced:
  |
  |  trying to reduce  MyTuple2Apply[(zero : Int), Int, String]
  |  failed since selector  (zero : Int)
  |  does not match  case (0 : Int) => Int
  |  and cannot be shown to be disjoint from it either.
  |  Therefore, reduction cannot advance to the remaining cases
  |
  |    case (1 : Int) => String
  |    case Int => Int | String
```

I'm not sure how to get this to typecheck. Would love some advice!

---

Here is a Scastie link that replicates the above snippets: [Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/hWqsBum9Saul6xkJUDJeBw)

Comment: Interesting. My question: What's a meaningful difference between the two? In other words, what can you do with a true union type `Int | String` that you can't do with the match type `MyTuple2Apply[(zero : Int), Int, String]`?